# toggleclass('d-block') multi input radio not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

We have many `radio input`.

```js
 
function showReferal() {
   document.querySelector('#referral_code').classList.remove('d-none');
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group row d-none" id="referral_code">
 <label for="referral_code">Referral Code</label>
 <div class="col-md-10">
  <input id="referral_code" type="text" class="form-control" name="referral_code">
 </div>
</div>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="google" value="1">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="friends" value="2">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="advertising" value="3">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="marketer" value="4" onclick="showReferal()">
```

> And when I click on `#marketer` should show `#referral_code`.

When I click on `advertising` and `google` and `friends` ,  `referral_code` must be hidden. only `marketer` be show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Alex Kudryashev's answer, but you can use the built-in `toggle` method instead of writing an `if` statement.

```js
function showReferal(show) {
  var refCode = document.querySelector('#referral_code');
  refCode.classList.toggle('d-none', !show); 
}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row d-none" id="referral_code">
  <label for="referral_code">Referral Code</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input id="referral_code" type="text" class="form-control" name="referral_code">
  </div>
</div>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="google" value="1" onclick="showReferal(false)">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="friends" value="2" onclick="showReferal(false)">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="advertising" value="3" onclick="showReferal(false)">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="marketer" value="4" onclick="showReferal(true)">
```

Comment: Good but I didn't use any more efficient approach to keep the OP simple.
Surely, it is better to `addEventListener` to all `[name="familiar"]` elements, remove redundant `id`s, and so on. It is great if the OP understand my *oversimplified* approach. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function from each radio button.

```js
function showReferal(show) {
  var refCode = document.querySelector('#referral_code');
  if (show) {
    refCode.classList.remove('d-none');
  } else if (refCode.classList.value.indexOf('d-none') === -1) {
    refCode.classList.add('d-none');
  }
}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row d-none" id="referral_code">
  <label for="referral_code">Referral Code</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input id="referral_code" type="text" class="form-control" name="referral_code">
  </div>
</div>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="google" value="1" onclick="showReferal(false)">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="friends" value="2" onclick="showReferal(false)">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="advertising" value="3" onclick="showReferal(false)">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="familiar" id="marketer" value="4" onclick="showReferal(true)">
```

Comment: You can use `classList.contains("d-none")` instead of `indexOf`. Or just add the class unconditionally, there's no harm on adding a class multiple times.

Comment: You can **hardly** use `.classList.contains` because `.classList` isn't an `array`.
`.className.indexOf` is mach better.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList. `contains()` is one of the methods of `Element.classList`.

Comment: You can also replace the whole `if` with `refCode.classList.toggle('d-none', !show);`